# add user include dir after standard include dir

Tags: c++, c, gcc

when using -Idir1 flag to add include path, gcc search dir1 BEFORE system standard include dir, e.g:

```
$ cpp -v /dev/null -I$HOME/glibc/include  -o /dev/null
```

gcc will search $HOME/glibc/include first,then the standard include dirs:

```
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

How to adjust include dir order, e.g: search standard include dir first, then the -Idir ?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use `-idirafter` key? See: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options

Comment: If you mean that GCC looks for *quotes* headers (declared with `" "`) defined locally first, and after globally, then this is how macro search is described in [C standard. 6.10.2 Source file inclusion/3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=182).

Comment: If your include isn't a system header you should use [`-iquote`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) then it won't be considered for includes using `<>` but only for ones using quotes

Comment: Because what I am compiling is glibc/iconv, it's not easy to distinguish
whether it's a system header(in code, using include <some.h>) or a user header(using include "some.h") , 
and @DmytroOvdiienko answer is most easy.
I created a github demo  project for this. (Eclipse CDT project, Ubutnu system)
https://github.com/stzdzyhs/gcc-inc-order
Thanks for your all!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There might some solutions for this, but [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73245575/add-user-include-dir-after-standard-include-dir/73304280#comment129356376_73245575) that [Dmytro Ovdiienko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145526/dmytro-ovdiienko) posted provided the answer:

> Did you try to use `-idirafter` key? See: [gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/…](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)